# How to connect MySQL database through two SSH hosts

Tags: ssh, mysql

How do I connect to MySQL database through two SSH hosts ?

Here is my situation: I have two SSH hosts as show below. MySQL is running in BOX2 host.

MyBox(GUI client) -----SSH(port 22)--->BOX1(IP: 190.xx.xx.xx)---SSH(port 22)--->BOX2(IP: 190.xx.xx.xx)[MySQL server]

My question is how do I connect if I have multiple SSH hosts to tunnel as shown above ?

Comment: Why can't you just SSH to Box2 directly? Or if your MySQL server was compiled with SSL support, you could just initiate an SSL connection to it directly without an SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `ProxyCommand` to connect transparently from MyBox to BOX2 (using BOX1 under the hood), so you can setup a `-L` redirection directly from MyBox to BOX2.
Please read: [transparent multihop SSH](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html) to get more details.